# How to float a ul in both directions?

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

Is it possible to have a "menu bar" made from a single `ul` and then float some `li`s  to the left and some to the right?  So my code right now is

```
<body>
    <header><nav><ul>
        <li><a href="pg1.html">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg2.html">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg3.html">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg4.html">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul></nav></header>
    ...
</body>
```

And the css:

```
header > nav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 2em;
}
header > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header > nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
header > nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
    color: white;
    line-height: 2em;
}
a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The menu items are all of course on the left, but can some be floated to the right without changing the HTML "significantly?"

Comment: Why do you need a `ul`? Having just `<nav> <a hreh="...> </nav>` is perfectly fine. And `a`s, by default, are inline elements. Could you please add a mockup or something that illustrates what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You could apply a class to the `<li>`s you want floated right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to the list items that you want on the right, and then add a CSS rule for `float:right;`

Example:

Add to your CSS:

```
    .right {
        float:right;
    }
```

Replace your HTML5 with this

```
 <header><nav><ul>
    <li><a href="pg1.html">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pg2.html">Menu2</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="pg3.html">Menu3</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="pg4.html">Menu4</a></li>
</ul></nav></header>
```

Another option would be to create 2 div's (one that floats left, the other floats right) and then put one list within each div.

Comment: Depending on where you add the CSS rule you might need to add !important to it so that it overrides your other declaration.  So the middle CSS line would need to be:  float:right !important;

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet create another class <strike>or id</strike> for list elements that float right. Here is a jsfiddle that I did to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z55hz/

stylesheet

```
header > nav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 2em;
}
header > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header > nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

li.other {
    float:right;

}

header > nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
    color: white;
    line-height: 2em;
}
a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
     <header><nav><ul>
        <li><a href="pg1.html">Menu1</a></li>
        <li class="other"><a href="pg2.html">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg3.html">Menu3</a></li>
        <li class="other"><a href="pg4.html">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul></nav></header>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, I changed it to class.